# Epic 4g Touch: Choose to route calls through Google Talk or Sprint

Tags: calls, google-voice, samsung-galaxy-s-2

A friend of mine just got the Epic 4g Touch (a.k.a. the Sprint version of the Samsung Galaxy s2).  He has installed the Google Voice app on all of his previous Android devices and there has always been an option somewhere to choose whether outgoing calls are routed through Sprint or Google.  This also changes which of his numbers shows up.  However, on his new phone, all calls come from his Google voice number and neither of us can find where to change it.

Is this a new "feature" intended to simplify the program?  Is it some restriction that the Sprint-branded software creates?  Or are we missing something?

Comment: Did he set up Sprint's Google Voice integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He had other problems so he has now switched Google Voice to use his Sprint number.